# D3: Create a grouped bar chart from json objects

Tags: javascript, json, charts, d3.js

I have some data like this:

```
[
 { id: 12, value1: "2.92", value2: "4.22", value3: "3.69" }
, 
 { id: 23, value1: "2.69", value2: "4.24", value3: "3.77" }
,
  ....
]
```

I want to create a horizontal grouped bar chart, so that there are 3 groups of bars, first all value1 bars (labeled as Value1), followed by all value2 bars and finally all value3 bars.

How can I do this - keeping in mind that the data will be updated dynamically in the future, so new data objects will be added and others will be removed. Guess I could use id as a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, supply or convert the data to an ordinary array or arrays
eg

```
data = [ [ 2.92, 4.22, 3.69], [2.69, 4.24, 3.77] ]
```

Now you can use d3.transpose to pivot the data so you get

```
  var tdata = d3.transpose(data);
```

gives you

```
   [ [2.92, 2.69], [4.22, 4.24], [3.69, 3.77]]
```

then here is a group bar from iaindillingham to use as a model (I've fixed his version to use the latest d3 library).  See it working here: http://bl.ocks.org/3532324

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try that. Does your approach work when updating the data of the chart?

Comment: I used your working example as a base now. How do I add a new series to that existing chart?

Comment: Try this page, http://needforair.com/blog/2012/05/09/d3-tutorial/  you will need to have an enter and and exit to add/remove data for each update.

Comment: Does anyone know why we need to transpose the data first (that is, why `d3.layout.stack()` works like that)? It seems like the things being stacked are the data points that belong to the original categories, so I'm not sure why the need for the intermediate step. Speed?