# D3 generate multiple graph for single json

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to generate multiple graph using a single json.i can only use one dataset.
i am able to generate only one graph in all P tag but i want to generate different graph in all P tag one for each dataset.

Html

```
<p class="graph1"></p>
<p class="graph1"></p>
<p class="graph1"></p>
<p class="graph1"></p>
<p class="graph1"></p>
```

Dataset

```
var dataset=[[2100, 2000, 3200],[2200, 3000, 3200],[1200, 1000, 5200],[1200, 2000, 3200],[1200, 3000, 3500]];
```

D3 Javascript

```
svg = d3.selectAll('.graph1').append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);
var rect1 =   svg.append("rect").attr("x",0).attr("y",3*h/4).attr("width",w).attr("height",rect_1_h)
        .style("fill",rect_1_color);
```

Comment: Do your `<p>` elements already exist or do you want to create them as part of the script?

Comment: You might also consider the alternate approach of having all the rectangles generated as grouped bars in a single svg, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180108/d3-create-a-grouped-bar-chart-from-json-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate graphs dynamically based on a dataset you can do so in one statement by joining your dataset with a selection. This can be done using the function [`data()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data).

For example if you wanted to generate rectangles with fill colours that you have stored in an array you could do so like this (I used your script just with a different dataset):

```
var dataset=[["blue"],["red"],["green"],["black"],["orange"]]; 
var rect_1_h =20;
var h =200;
var w=200;
var rects = d3.select("body").selectAll('.graph1')
 .data(dataset)
.enter().append("p").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h)
.append("rect")
 .attr("x",0)
 .attr("y",3*h/4)
 .attr("width",w)
 .attr("height",rect_1_h)
 .style("fill",function(d) { return d[0];});
```

Here is a jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jve6V/)