# d3 bar chart with sub categories

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Is it possible to have sub categories in a bar chart in d3? I don't think it's possible out of the box, but maybe someone has an idea of how to do it. An example would be sales of products (A, B, C) per month:

```
  =   =   
  =   =     = 
  = = =   = =
  = = =   = = =
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+- ...
| A B C | A B C |  ...
|  Jan  |  Feb  |  ...
```

I'm not sure how I would go about adding another dataset to a bar chart.

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180108/d3-create-a-grouped-bar-chart-from-json-objects

Comment: If D3 was a box it would come as a Stanley knife, thick cardboard and a metal ruler. Self assembly is (nearly) always required but you get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: chart showing d3.js producing a grouped chart]

Take each set of data you have, added it a list and then transpose the data.

```
var dataA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var dataB = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var dataC = [5, 4, 3, 4, 5];

var dataAll = [dataA, dataB, dataC];
var dataT = d3.transpose(dataAll);
```

In D3.js this is not too difficult and the `d3.transpose` will transposition of the data for you. The hardest part really is doing in such a way that is easy to read/update. Bind outer list to a `g` object. I would use a transformation on this group to shift it to the right by the position in the list. Then when you are dealing with individual `rect`s later you don't have to calculate the correct position of the month. This will also make labels much easier and as always good separations of concerns. You can then bind the inner list to `rect`'s and add a little color to give the chart shown above.

```
var chart = d3.selectAll('#chartArea')
    .append('svg')

var month = chart.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataT)
    .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', function(d,i){return 'translate(' + x(i) + ', 0)';});

month.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function (d) {return d;}) 
    .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d, i){return x(i/groups);})
        .attr('y', function(d){return h-y(d);})
        .attr('width', function(){return x(1/groups);})
        .attr('height', function(d){return y(d);})
        .attr('fill', function(d, i){return groupColor(i);})
```

A working example is on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hKvwa/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea d3 was able to deal with multiple dimensions. I've been playing around with your jsfiddle, but one thing I couldn't figure out is how to add a minor axis on the chart (i.e. A, B, C in the above example for each month). Is there anything d3 can help with or do I have to draw it myself? Here's how I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8yzd/1/

Comment: I checked and scale does not accept a nested domain which is a shame. You can draw it yourself along with each of your bar however keep in mind that it could count towards `chartjunk` as the information will be repeated so many times http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk . Positioning becomes difficult as space will quickly run out. A key may be more appropriate.

Comment: With "key map" you mean a chart legend, I presume. I'll try that instead... Thanks for your help.