# Increasing width and spacing of major groups in a d3 nested group graph

Tags: d3.js

I was able to create a chart using sub groups in the manner described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710014/d3-bar-chart-with-sub-categories).  The results look like this:

[image]

I'd like to be able to control width of the colored bars as the number of categories within them increases, rather than just have the category width decrease in width to fit a constant major group width.  As a result of this, as the data increases, I'd like to have the "excess" graph just go off the div, like so:

[image]  and the excess would be access by means of scrolling, I guess with .css .scroll property.

How does one achieve this kind of look?

Comment: This is just setting the width of the bars, isn't it?

Comment: If you just increase the width of the bars, they'll overlap between major categories.  I need to keep the padding between the major categories.  I'll get some code up to clarify the issue.